# Code to save last changes/modifications in any Sheet of the Workbook isn't accurate

Tags: vba, excel, events, event-handling

I have previously raised an issue of which I have been using a last saved code to register changes on each sheet of the code.

The time in which changes are made will be registered on an index sheet to show the last modified timing of each sheet.

However the code registers the time of which i visited the sheet and not modify hence making it inaccurate.

Is there any other more efficient and accurate solutions to register the changes made to the sheet and not visit instead?

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal target As Range)

    If Sh.Name = "Index" Then Exit Sub

    i = Sh.Index

    With Sheets("Index")

        .Cells(i + 2, 1) = Sh.Name
        .Cells(i + 2, 2) = Now

    End With

End Sub
```

Here is the code

Comment: There must be more code. That code will only react to cells being edited on a sheet, not simply activating a sheet.

Comment: How can i possibly expand the code? Any idea? @Rory

Comment: No, I mean you must **already** have more code if what you describe is true. That code simply will not do what you describe.

Comment: Okay,so what do i do to meet my requirement? @Rory

Comment: Find the other code, or whatever is triggering the sheetchange, and remove it.

Comment: I do not know which of it is triggering.. @Rory

Comment: Well without the file, I can't say.

Comment: mp.xlsm - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9gYthfgnZIUM2thNTN0ckVxQWs/view?usp=docslist_api

Comment: Thats the URL sflr!  @Rory

Comment: @Niva : how my godness... I'm almost color blind after taking a look at your file... Don't put so many colors/images in background, put a grey like color, it'll be enough! And for unknown reason, I had to close your file like 20 times before it stop popping open again...

Comment: You meant the background? Lol thanks for the feedback anyways!! @R3uK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your method isn't good because you use the sheet's index**, which represent the place/order at which the sheet is placed regarding other sheets. So **if you move your sheets, you code will overwrite** the row that was used for another sheet.

So I based **my proposition on the sheet name** (that can change too, but it'll **only add a new line and not overwrite existing data**), and added in the third column the range that was modified.

Give this a try :

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Sh.Name = "Index" Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 And Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Dim AlreadyExist As Boolean, _
        LastRow As Integer, _
        WsI As Worksheet

    Set WsI = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Index")
    With WsI
        LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        AlreadyExist = False
        For i = 1 To LastRow
            'Look for the good row to update
            If .Cells(i, 1) <> Sh.Name Then
            Else
                AlreadyExist = True
                .Cells(i, 2) = Now
                .Cells(i, 3) = Target.Address(False, False, xlA1)
            End If
        Next i
        'If the sheet didn't exist, add a new line for it
        If AlreadyExist Then
        Else
            .Cells(LastRow + 1, 1) = Sh.Name
            .Cells(LastRow + 1, 2) = Now
            .Cells(LastRow + 1, 3) = Target.Address(False, False, xlA1)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Okay i get your concern here, but does it meet the requirement of registering the changes made for each sheet?

Comment: Yes... It does... Try it and you'll see for yourself! ;)

Comment: i tried but it is still registering the time i visited the page:/ Really do not know why it is not happening. I have attached the link above if you want to refer to the excel workbook!

Comment: Mkay... it might be in your file, but I've already checked and mine doesn't register visited time. So do you have other events in sheet's modules or in thisworkbook module?

Comment: I have a running clock in the sheet module. Does it affect?

Comment: Sub runClock(ByVal flag As Boolean)
    Dim functionWithParam As String
    Range("A1").Value = Now():  DoEvents
    functionWithParam = "'runClock" & Chr(34) & flag & Chr(34) & "'"
    If clockStart Then Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1), functionWithParam
End Sub

Comment: Yes definitely, as this will rewrite the time each second in your sheet... So your problem definitely comes from that clock! ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93021/discussion-between-niva-and-r3uk).

Comment: You are very welcome! ;) As all of your clocks seems to be placed in [A1], I amended the code (2nd line) to exclude a modification in every sheet's [A1]. That should allow to keep your clocks if you really want to! ;)

Answer (score 1):

My solution to your question using last modified date of the file. It works well for file which is already saved.

```
 Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal target As Range)

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim MaxRange As Range
    Dim Maxvalue As Double


        Set wb = ThisWorkbook
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Index")
        Set MaxRange = ws.Columns(2)


        sPath = wb.FullName

        'Debug.Print Sh.Name

      Maxvalue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(MaxRange)

        'Debug.Print Format(Maxvalue, "DD/mm/YYYY")

    If Sh.Name = "Index" Then Exit Sub

    ' Find the Last row

    lastrow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Set f = fs.GetFile(sPath)
    filemoddate = CDate(f.DateLastModified)

      ' Debug.Print filemoddate

      ' Debug.Print CDate(ws.Cells(lastrow, 2).Value)

     If filemoddate > CDate(Maxvalue) Then

        With ws.UsedRange
             Set rfound = .Find(Sh.Name, LookIn:=xlValues)
                If Not rfound Is Nothing Then
                     lastrow = rfound.Row

                ' Print if the Modified Date if the file name present

                     ws.Cells(lastrow, 2).Value = filemoddate
                Else

                ' Print if the Modified Date and Sheet Name if the file 'name is not present

                   ws.Cells(lastrow + 1, 1).Value = Sh.Name
                    ws.Cells(lastrow + 1, 2).Value = filemoddate
                 End If
        End With

   End If


   Set f = Nothing
   Set fs = Nothing
   Set ws = Nothing
   Set wb = Nothing
   Set rfound = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: This for the file and not respective sheet? Because it does not seem to work on a sheet basis!

Comment: Whenever there is a change in the modification date in the file, the result ( modified date and respective sheet name) will be stored in the index sheet.

Comment: Hope it meets your requirement

Answer (score 1):

If this it the only macro in the workbook, you could opt to use the "Track Changes" feature instead of writing a macro. (Note: macros cannot be edited in shared workbooks). Once the feature is turned on, you can view the changes by navigating to Track Changes>Highlight Changes>Select "List Changes on a New Worksheet". You can also choose to display all changes or just the changes since the last time the work book was saved.

Here is a link with more information on the features that are and are not supported in a shared workbook [MS Shared Workbooks](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/use-a-shared-workbook-to-collaborate-49b833c0-873b-48d8-8bf2-c1c59a628534#bmunsupported)

Sample of Track Changes History worksheet:
[image: Sample History Page from Tracking Changes]

Comment: That seems impressive! Thanks alot, i would consider this alternative as well:)